# Can't install Ubuntu or Linux Mint

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, nomodeset

I can't get Ubuntu or Linux Mint to install on my new computer.  The system acts like it continues to load and I hear a sound like it wants me to login.  All I see on the screen is the information below. ( I have the latest BIOS for my motherboard)

```
[   0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[130] not in IVRS table
[   0.000000] AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
[   4.939736] nouveau 0000:42:00.0 disp: chid 0 mthd 0000 data 00000000 00001000 00000001
```

This computer is an AMD 2950x with an Nvidia GTX 1080Ti.  I can't get the normal grub menu to show up while trying this install by pressing the Shift key. If I switch the boot to UEFI and press Esc I do get a grub menu but not what I expect, and I am lost on what to do to fix the graphics issue.

I have read about the `nomodeset` kernel boot option, but without the grub line to modify, I have no idea how to do this. I have tried Linux Mint 19 and Ubuntu 18.04. The only one that I can't even attempt to install and get to work is Slackware.

I was able to get into the installer thanks to Karel!  F6 after the bios screen got me into the splash screen when nothing else would.

Comment: Sometimes you have to press a different key than Shift to get to the grub command line. Please refer to the [nomodeset tag info](https://askubuntu.com/tags/nomodeset/info). If you get stuck after that please update your question by editing it.

Comment: UEFI & escape is correct, what do you expect on grub menu? You use e for edit and scroll down to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset. Many AMD also need IOMMU set in UEFI and maybe this parameter in addition. `acpi=off` and/or `iommu=soft`  What motherboard?

Comment: oldfred,  It was not the normal grub menu that I have seen for many years.  It was just the word grub and if you hit tab it would bring you up a list of options.  This was more like a grub rescue screen than anything else I have seen before.  The motherboard is an Asus Prime X399-A.

Comment: After doing the F6 and getting into the installer, I then am able to see the normal grub menu to add the nomodeset there and fix up my grub loader.  Thanks again karel for the help, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> and getting into the installer, I then am able to see the normal GRUB menu to add `nomodeset` there and fix GRUB.

Source: [comment by karel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094088/cant-install-ubuntu-or-linux-mint/1094100#comment1801485_1094088), and [nomodeset tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/nomodeset/info).

Comment: You may consider ["accepting" your answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future. It's absolutely fine to accept your own answer.